# Service object not mocked with data?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, springjunit4classrunner

```
Service object not mocked from controller testcase return empty object here is the below code 

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Main.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @ActiveProfiles(ApplicationConstants.DEVELOPMENT_PROFILE)
    public class EmployeeControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext   webAppContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    EmployeeCompositeService  employeeCompositeService;
    @InjectMocks 
    EmployeeController employeeController;

    String name = "mike";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webAppContext).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetEmployees() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(employeeCompositeService.getEmployeesByName(name)).thenReturn(getEmployees());
        String url = URIConstants.ROOT_CONTEXT + URIConstants.EMPLOYEE;
        MvcResult result =
        mockMvc.perform(post(url)
                        .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .content(convertObjectToJsonBytes(name))
                        .andExpect(status().isOk())
                        .andExpect(content().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].employeeName").value("Mike"))
                        .andReturn();
        String jsonContent = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        LOGGER.debug("jsonContent: {}",jsonContent);

    }

    protected byte[] convertObjectToJsonBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object);
    }

    private List<Employee> getEmployees(){
    //here is the logic to get List of employees to return. When the mockito call is invoked.
    }

    }

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstants.ROOT_CONTEXT)
public EmployeeController{
@Autowired
private EmployeeCompositeService employeeCompositeService;

    @RequestMapping(value=URIConstants.EMPLOYEE, method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = INPUT_FORMAT, produces = OUTPUT_FORMAT)
    public List<Employees> getEmployees(@RequestBody String name){
        return employeeCompositeService.getEmployeesByName(name); //When invoke this method it calls inner service but not returns the mocked object.

    }
}
```

I have a service call in side EmployeeController i.e

```
employeeCompositeService.getEmployees(String name)
```

So I have mocked in the EmployeeControllerTestcase i.e

```
@Mock EmployeeCompositeService  employeeCompositeService;
```

when I run the controller testcase it invokes further services calls and repository and hit the database

So I doesn't want to call inner services returns the results form this call `employeeCompositeService.getEmployeesByName(name);` from controller.

Can you please tell me what I did wrong in the above code Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EmployeeCompositeService` mock object is created but isn't injected anywhere. This is initialising a class member in the test but since it is not being injected into the controller, the real, database-facing implementation is being used. To inject the mock into the controller, declare the controller as a class member in the test and annotate it using the `org.mockito.InjectMocks` annotation. This will take the class members from the test with the `@Mock` annotation and inject them into the fields of controller that implement the same interface.

The next step is to inject the controller into the `MockMvc` object by assigning it as `mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeController).build()`.

Comment: Update the code with @InjectMocks EmployeeController employeeController;       and recheck it sitll employeeCompositeService.getEmployeesByName(name); invokes repo logic and hit the database. not resolved it.

Comment: The `EmployeeController` you've injected into your test isn't injected into `mockMvc`. I imagine you could say something like `mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeController).build()`.